# How can I make different generic function in type script?

Tags: typescript

I have function like this

```
export const registerResource = <T, H, M, I extends object, R extends object>(serverConfig: IResourceServerConfig<T, H>, option: IRegisterResourceOption<T, H, M, I, R> = {}) => {
...
}
```

So I will call look like this

```
registerResource(foo,bar)
```

But I would like to definition only 2 type T & H like this

```
registerResource<any, number>(foo,bar)
```

But it's not work, did I'm doing stupid and how can I resolve that.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify `T` and `H` at the call site and let the remaining type arguments be inferred, that feature is not currently supported by TypeScript but hopefully it will be soon; see the [open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  The current workaround is to change your function into a function with some type parameters that returns a function with the remaining type parameters:

```
export const registerResource = <T, H>(serverConfig: IResourceServerConfig<T, H>) =>
  <M, I extends object, R extends object>(option: IRegisterResourceOption<T, H, M, I, R> = {}) => {
  // ...
};
registerResource<any, number>(foo)(bar);
```

(I assume your example was based on real code that is actually using `M`, `I`, and `R` for something, otherwise you could just replace them with `{}`, `object`, and `object` and not have this problem.)

Comment: Thanks, but I think if I change my func into 2 curry func(func => func), It's look weird in my case, 2nd way is also work but it will loose some properties:    
`
const a = registerResource<IPractitioner, IDataServerResponse<IPractitioner>, any, object, object>(serverConfig, {
 addResourceProps: (resource) => ({newOne: 1})
})
` 
In that case it's will not receive the `newOne` is also the properties to return 

a.resource.newOne (not work). Sample code at here: https://gist.github.com/tomzaku/f46e5341ff82527ff530fc25f8f3e5e8

Comment: I don't have another solution to offer at this time than the "weird" currying.